# How do I delete the first, third, fifth and sixth columns of a text file?

Tags: python

I want to delete the first, third, fifth and sixth columns of this text file:

```
10  11  12  46  48  39
20  21  22  34  23  24
30  31  32  78  29  38
40  41  42  21  43  12
```

My code looks like this:

```
f = open("Exercise2.txt", "r")

g = open("Output.txt", "w")


for line in f:

   if line.strip():

       g.write("\t".join(line.split()[1:-1]) + "\n")

f.close()

g.close()
```

But I can't delete a column in between two columns that I want to stay. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = open("Exercise2.txt", 'r')
g = open("Output.txt", "w")

for line in f:
    g.write("\t".join(x for index, x in enumerate(line.split()) if index in [1,3]) + "\n")

f.close()
g.close()
```

`enumerate` will create a list of tuples with `(index, value)`. For example, for your first line:

```
>>> list(enumerate("10  11  12  46  48  39".split()))
[(0, '10'), (1, '11'), (2, '12'), (3, '46'), (4, '48'), (5, '39')]
```

That way you can compare the index (or column).

Then you check `if index in [1,3]` (if in the second or fourth column), and `"\t".join(...)` the `x` (the numbers in this case) values together.

Output:

```
11  46
21  34
31  78
41  21
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to read the file as a csv remove the columns and write it to a different file.